# alert addAction(action) giving me a error message saying action is a unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I tried to add this simple Ibaction code to the uibuttion but it keeps giving me a error message saying action is a unresolved identifier.
Can you please help?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func hello() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "hello", message: "daaaammmmmn", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your variable is named `okAction`, not `action`

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo: You wrote `let okAction = ...` while you do `alert.addAction(action)`.

You should replace `alert.addAction(action)` with `alert.addAction(okAction)`

Answer (score 0):

`action` variable isn't declared here, it should be `okAction`